# Edge and opening a new page

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Is it possible to right click on a link shown by **Edge** and after selecting 'Open in a new Tab' force the new tab to become the active one instead of the current?

(Not sure if, in the english version of Edge, the first link in the popup menu is exactly called *'Open in a new Tab'*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ctrl+Shift+click** opens a link in a new tab *and* switches to it.

Can't find formal documentation for Edge, but it's been inherited from IE (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/internet-explorer-keyboard-shortcuts#1TC=windows-7 under '*working with tabs*').

Comment: That's good enough. I was looking for some kind of configuration option but this makes the deal sealed

Comment: @Steve IE used to have an `always switch to new tabs when they are created` option under Internet Options / General / Tabs. The option still exists in the same place in Windows 10, but unfortunately doesn't seem to apply to Edge.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, You can move your cursor on a link, then try
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>pressing wheel</kbd> in Windows as well.

Comment: This is **closing** the tab!

Comment: @Toto Nope. Not for me!